# replace/substitute pattern with file content

Tags: sed

```
sed -i "/xxxxxxxxxxxx/r inc-sausage" git.html
sed -i "/xxxxxxxxxxxx/d" git.html
```

First I insert the content of inc-sausage when xxxxxxxxxxxx is found

Second I delete xxxxxxxxxxxx

Both commands do exactly what I want. But how can I combine both sed commands to a single one?
I tried

```
sed -i "s/xxxxxxxxxxxx/r inc-sauasge" git.html
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For starters, you coould concatenate both `sed` commands into one line and avoid repeating the search string, like this:

```
sed -i -e "/xxxxxxxxxxxx/r inc-sausage" -e "//d" git.html
```

Also, if you want to delete `xxxxxxxxxxxx` only and not other things in its line, you could do that instead:

```
sed -i -e "/xxxxxxxxxxxx/r inc-sausage" -e "s///" git.html
```

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you:

```
sed -i '/xxxxxxxxxxxx/{r inc-sausage'$'\n''d}' git.html
```

Explanation:

See [here](http://sed.sourceforge.net/sedfaq5.html#s5.9) why `$'\n'` is necessary. Also note that `d` command must be last as it deletes the pattern space and then immediately starts the next cycle.

Or for GNU sed:

```
sed -i '/xxxxxxxxxxxx/s|.*|cat inc-sausage|e' git.html
```